# Is the following question acceptable for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the following question on Stack Overflow but wanted to know if it's appropriate for this site or another:

> I currently have WAMP installed on my Windows 7 machine and ActivePerl installed as well. I would like to have my WAMP/Apache run any Perl script regardless of the shebang line.
>
> How would I make such a change possible in Apache?

Comment: I always thought the she-bang line on Windows wasn't really important.  This was way back in 5.8, so it may have changed.

Comment: Well I generally thought so too. However I'm noticing a lot of tutorials on the matter actually change the shebang to that of the directory.

Comment: Maybe webmasters.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @AbZy this does definitely not look like Webmasters material to me.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I found 400+ questions tagged Apache there. It was just a wild guess

Comment: @PaulWilliams I would suggest trying what you're suggesting, and seeing if it causes any problems. If it causes problems, then ask a Stack Overflow problem on the specific problem you're seeing. These general, "I haven't tried it but it could fail" questions are usually closed as 'not a real question'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your potential question is that you haven't actually tried to do what you're asking. That tends to attract close votes, because the community wants to see some sort of effort.

I suggest that you actually try to do what you're asking, that is try to run perl scripts that don't share the standard shebang line. If it doesn't work, come to us with the errors you see (which is important because people search on errors) and write a specific question based on the actual problem you face.

If you do that, it'll make the question on topic for Stack Overflow (since it seems like any potential problem would be centered on how perl scripts are run on varying systems).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider asking on [superuser](http://www.superuser.com) since it's more like configuration and how you set up your environment than programming or actual program writing.

> > What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> computer hardware, computer software, or personal and home computer
>   networking and **it is not about …
>
> programming** and software development, video games or consoles,
>   websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
>   electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except
>   insofar as they interface with your computer, issues specific to
>   corporate IT support and networks, asking for a shopping or product
>   recommendation,